# Issues with session variables and cffileupload

Tags: session, coldfusion, upload

I don't have access to make any changes to the coldfusion administrator as I am on a shared host.  But I am running cf9 and am trying to use the  tag for multiple image uploads. Everything looks good until I click the upload button and get a 302 error returned.  After some research I found that was because this part of my code is behind an admin login and the session variables don't get passed over through the flash with the  tag and then the redirect to the login page occurs.  From what I've seen the solution to this is to make sure `SESSIONMANAGEMENT="Yes"` in the Application.cfm file and append `?#urlEncodedFormat(session.urltoken)#` to the url where the upload is supposed to happen.  The only other thing I've seen was going into the coldfusion administrator and changing the type of session management.  Either `Java EE servlet session management` or `ColdFusion session management` which I cannot do.

I was hoping there were still other options to get this to work, or maybe I am doing something incorrectly that someone can point out.

Here is an example of my code:
test.cfm

```
<script> 
var foo = function(result) 
{ 
    alert(ColdFusion.JSON.encode(result)); 
} 
</script> 
<cffileupload url="uploadFiles.cfm?#urlEncodedFormat(session.urltoken)#" width=600 height=400/>
```

uploadFiles.cfm:

```
<cffile action="uploadAll" destination="#Application.filePath#Gallery\" nameconflict="makeunique"> 
<cfset str.STATUS = 200>
<cfset str.MESSAGE = "passed">
<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(str)#</cfoutput>
```

The destination path is a correct absolute path.

Edit: Was this question posted twice by me?  If so, is that why I was downvoted?

Comment: I would have accepted an answer if one had worked.  While everyone who contributed gave good insight and offered good help, none were correct in my situation.  I ended up using an almost completely other solution.  Thank you.

Comment: In that case, it's acceptable and appropriate to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: I don't have enough of a ranking to answer my own question.  My solution was to just create more then 1 file input rather then the multiple file upload.  Not really a solution, just giving up.

Answer (score 1):

The appending session token to the URL workaround is not needed after CF9.0.1

> **Enhancement in ColdFusion 9.0.1**
>
> In ColdFusion 9.0.1, the fileupload
>   control passes the session information implicitly to the target page
>   if session management is turned on either in Application.cfc or
>   Application.cfm.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec18238-7fd0.html

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which version of CF I am using beyond CF9.  I may have 9.0.1 or just 9.0, just not sure.  Is there a way I can find out like in php like with phpinfo().  I rarely use coldfusion so I'm not too familiar with it.  Also, if I am using 9.0.1, what other reasons could there be for me getting a 302 error?

Comment: Server version is `9,0,0,251028 ` I got it from running <cfdump var="#SERVER#" />

Comment: time to ask your host to upgrade. :)  CF 9.0.1 brings a lot of bug fixes as well as new features!

Comment: So it looks like I'm doing everything correct?  And this is probably just a bug with my coldfusion version?  I can't believe there is no way to make this work, even if it is some sort of work around.  Does anyone have any ideas other then have my host upgrade on a shared server, because 1 person asking for an upgrade probably won't matter and they probably won't upgrade for fear of breaking current code.

Comment: usually that workaround of yours would work.  I'm can't think of other reason why there's a 302.  More: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/11/11/Important-notes-about-ColdFusion-9s-new-multi-file-uploader

Comment: Allright, I appreciate your help.  I'm thinking of another workaround where I put this needed file somewhere else (not behind the admin login)  as the page is all coldfusion the "view source" wouldn't show anything if someone was to navigate to it.  Chances are slim that someone would know what type of data to send the page to have it able to upload files that may be malicious.  I'll post here if it works.